# how to get viewers by time range from view start time and view durations?

Tags: php, mysql, time, range, usage-statistics

I have a little problem to make statistics.

people can watch videos on my website. I store some datas in mysql table videos_has_views

```
IdUser = the watcher ID
ddv = date of view = the start time of the view
duration = the duration of the view
```

---

what i would like to get is an array of how many viewers were active by time range.

**For example :**

```
John start viewing at 2017-01-01 00:00:00 and watch video for 1800 seconds (30mn)

Hodor start viewing at 2017-01-01 00:00:00 and watch video for 1200 seconds (20mn)

Rob start viewing at 2017-01-01 00:10:00 and watch video for 1800 seconds (30mn)
```

**I try to get an array like**

```
From 0 to 10min : 2 viewers (john + hodor)    
From 10 to 20min : 3 viewers    
From 20 to 30 : 2 viewers (john + Rob)    
From 30 to 40 : 1 viewer (rob)
```

---

But I don't know how to attack this problem with mysql ... or with a loop in php ? 
if anybody have an idea for me i'll be very thankfull

Comment: You are not concrete enuff here. But lookup functions in mysql like `BETWEEN` and DATE functions. I thing you can create an SQL for: Give my all viewers that have seen video xy, from Y-M-DH:I:S, for 10 minutes. But you have to try it for yourself. google more and you will find some hints. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/

Comment: What's your SQL table looking like?

Comment: Show us the table and some example data.. no image but text

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT
  CASE
  WHEN duration BETWEEN 0 AND 600 THEN '0to10'
  WHEN duration BETWEEN 601 AND 1200 THEN '10to20'
  WHEN duration BETWEEN 1201 AND 1800 THEN '20to30'
  ELSE 'moreThan30'
  END as duration_range,
  count(IdUser) as cnt
FROM videos_has_views
GROUP BY duration_range
ORDER BY duration_range ASC;
```

You can make as many ranges as You want ... it works (at least in MySQL 5.7)
If You want to include names in another column then (since we're using GROUP BY) You can use GROUP CONCAT from names/userIDs or whatever :)

Comment: hi. thank for your answer.
I think it is a good tracks but not the goal I search. Here we found how many users watched beetween X seconds and X+10 seconds regardless the starttime of watching.
What I wan to do is to create a curve of audience at time T during my broadcast. Here, Your method is working only if every users start watching at the same time :-/